# Replace slashes between double quote characters using sed

Tags: sed

In an HTML file, I'm trying to replace the slashes `/` that appear between a pair of double quotes `"` with `%20`.
For example instead of having this line:

```
<a href="i/love/unix">i/am/happy!</a>
```

I want to get:

```
<a href="i%20love%20unix">i/am/happy!</a>
```

I'm trying to use the `sed` command something like this:

```
sed -e 's/\(^.*href=\"\).*\(\".*\)/\1@@@\2/g'
```

But instead of '@@@', I'm trying to use another `sed` command to replace `/` with `%20`:

```
's/\//%20/g'
```

Is it possible to combine these two `sed` commands together?

Comment: I don't see any differences in the two examples your trying to compare with i/am/happy. Can you please restate them.

Comment: yes its in <a href> (I edited it now) "i%20love%20unix" instead of "i/love/unix"

Comment: While it probably can be done in `sed`, I don't think it is the appropriate tool for the job; it is far too much like hard work and contorted thinking.  Use Python or Perl or another scripting language of your choice.

Comment: I'm trying to do it in 1-2 lines and not in a script. I doen't have to use only sed, it can be maybe cut, awk, or any other command, but I stil didn't figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
echo '<a href="i/love/unix">i/am/happy!</a>' |
sed 's/"[^"]*"/\n&/g;h;s/[^"\n]*\(\n"[^"]*"\)[^"\n]*/\1/g;s/\//%20/g;H;g;:a;s/\n"[^"]*"\(.*\n\)\n\("[^"]*"\)/\2\1/;ta;s/\n//'
<a href="i%20love%20unix">i/am/happy!</a>
```

Explanation:

- `s/"[^"]*"/\n&/g` globally insert a `\n` before each intended string i.e. `"..."`
- `h` make a copy in the hold space (HS)
- `s/[^"\n]*\(\n"[^"]*"\)[^"\n]*/\1/g` remove everything else
- `s/\//%20/g` replace `/`'s by `%20`'s
- `H` append the amended replacements to the original line
- `g` overwrite the pattern space with the HS.
- `:a;s/\n"[^"]*"\(.*\n\)\n\("[^"]*"\)/\2\1/;ta` one at a time replace the old with new
- `s/\n//` delete the `\n` introduced when the `H` was used

Try inserting `l0` in the above solution to see what is in the pattern space.

Comment: @user1509241 see added explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the variety, here is a solution in `awk`.  You can put it all on one line:

```
bash$ echo '<a href="i/love/unix">i/am/happy!</a>' |
   awk -v FS='"' -v OFS='"' '{ for (i=2; i<NF; i+=2) { gsub("/", "%20", $i); } print }'
<a href="i%20love%20unix">i/am/happy</a>
```

I think that it is more readable on multiple lines:

```
bash$ echo '<a href="i/love/unix">i/am/happy!</a>' | awk -F \" -v OFS=\" '{
>   for (i=2; i<NF; i+=2) {
>      gsub("/", "%20", $i)
>   }
>   print
> }'
<a href="i%20love%20unix">i/am/happy</a>
```