# sed replace capital letters with a pattern

Tags: regex, sed

I have an xml file with lines like this:

`android:background="@drawable/WhiteButtonSelector"`

I need to replace capital letters with underscores and lowercase characters.
For example, the sample string above must be:

`android:background="@drawable/white_button_selector"`

Only text in double quotes must be replaced. Lines without `drawable` must be left unchanged.

Comment: Does it have to be `sed`?

Comment: If you search SO for `convert camelcase to underscores`, you'll find solutions in many languages. Hopefully one of them will be something you can use.

Comment: Actually I came up to the following solution: 1) replace capital letters with underscore lower case letters and then replace slash-underscore with slash
cat $i | gsed ':a; /drawable.*[A-Z]/{s/\(drawable\/\)\(.*\)\([A-Z]\)\(.*\)\(\"\)/\1\2_\L\3\4\5/g; ta}; s/\/_/\//g'

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/drawable/{s/"[^"]*"/\n&/g;h;s/[^"\n]*\(\n"[^"]*"\)[^"\n]*/\1/g;s/[A-Z]/_/g;H;g;:a;s/\n"[^"]*"\(.*\n\)\n\("[^"]*"\)/\2\1/;ta;s/\n//}' file
```

- check for "drawable" in line
- For remainder, I referred to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11379207/1754832)

*** In OS X, one can use `gsed` by installing it with brew, `brew install gnu-sed`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/drawable/{h;s/\b[A-Z]/\l&/g;s/\B[A-Z]/_\l&/g;G;s/.*(".*").*\n(.*)".*"/\2\1/}' file
```

Restrict the process to those lines that contain `drawable` within them.

Make a copy of the line and then replace capitals at the start of a word with lowercase and capitals within a word with underscore and lowercase.

Combine the original line with the processed line and via substitution constitute a new line.

N.B. This expects one such variable per line.